# Discord.py: How to schedule a operation every month or week?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to execute a function every week of month, but I tried  schedule and others but they are not working . To explain better, I want a way in python to execute a function every week or month. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean "are not working"? What did you try? Are you on a Mac? Cron is a nice tool. https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html

Answer (score 1):

Take loop like this:

```
import time, datetime, sys

@task.loop(seconds = x)
async def loop_x():
   ...
```

x give for 604800 seconds and this is week